# Python index error: list index out of range

Tags: python, matrix, indexing, error-handling

I am programming an experiment on Otree in which players type in their names and participate in a competition on who donate the most threes. The trees are entered via a form field. Round number is a predefined variable. And every player gets an id when he enters the experiment by default (starting from 1)
I already programmed the whole code and it works with up to 5 participants, but now I should program it for up to 8 participants. When I try to enter the number of participants on Otree, I receive the error message "index error: list index out of range".

Error occurs in the line `matrix[p.id_in_group - 1][0] = p.name
matrix[p.id_in_group - 1][self.round_number] = p.cumulative_donated_trees`

so I guess the initialization of the matrix is wrong? 
I just want to have a Matrix with 2 columns: names and trees (and index column of course) and n rows (n = number of players)```

models.py:

```
class Donation(Page):
    try:
        form_model = 'player'
        form_fields = ['donation']

 def vars_for_template(self):
            names = []
            trees = []
            sortedtrees = []
            anzahlspalten = 0
            for p in self.subsession.get_players():
                if self.round_number == 1:
                    matrix[p.id_in_group - 1][0] = p.name
                matrix[p.id_in_group - 1][self.round_number] = p.cumulative_donated_trees
            for i in range(0, Constants.number_of_players):
                names.append(matrix[i][0])
                trees.append(matrix[i][self.round_number])
            sortedtrees = sorted(trees, reverse=True)
            anzahlspalten = len(sortedtrees)         
            for l in range(0, anzahlspalten):
                if self.player.cumulative_donated_trees == sortedtrees[l]:
                    self.player.current_position = str(l + 1)
```

models.py:

```
name = models.StringField(label="Your first name:")
    transcribed_text = models.LongStringField()
    levenshtein_distance = models.IntegerField()
    guthaben = models.CurrencyField(initial=c(0))
    cumulative_guthaben = models.CurrencyField()
    cumulative_donation = models.FloatField(null=True)
    right_answer = models.BooleanField()
    right_answer_text = models.StringField()
    treatmentgroup = models.StringField()
    donation = models.FloatField(min=c(0))
    no_trees = models.FloatField(initial=0.0)
    cumulative_donated_trees = models.FloatField()
    current_position = models.StringField()
    spielstand = models.StringField()
```

Treceback:

```
File "c:\users\wiwi-admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\otree\views\abstract.py" in get_context_data
  338.             user_vars = self.vars_for_template()

File "C:\Users\Wiwi-Admin\Desktop\Backup Version 2 - Competition WITHIN Treatmentgroups\Master thesis code\__pycache__\oTree\my_environmental_surveyTG4\pages.py" in vars_for_template
  252.                     matrix[p.id_in_group - 1][0] = p.name

Exception Type: IndexError at /p/tgv0j88z/my_environmental_surveyTG4/Donation/7/
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

Comment: Try printing matrix, self.round_number and p.id_in_group to verify they are what you expect. I am guessing it happens after  self.round_number is not equal to 1.

Comment: What is your guess about the matter? When I play the game, the error always occurs in the first round already (self.round.number == 1)

Comment: Can you add "print(matrix)" just above the line that returns an error and outside the "if" statement.